# Sending POST request to a server that uses a self signed certificate

Tags: java, security, post, certificate

I need to send a POST request to a server that uses some levels of security. Unfortunately I don't know much about self signed certificates, I never used or studied it.

In the developer guide of the service it sais that the server uses a "public 1024-bit self signed certificate".

What does it mean? I've to create a certificate or I've to ask for it?
If i've to create a certificate, then how I should use it? 
I'm implementing the client in Java

Comment: You might have to set something on your request to not verify the trust relationship of the cert on the destination.  I'm not certain how to do this in java.

Comment: "Self-signed" means that there will be no chain of trust in the default trust store for the JVM.  This means you'll have to either ignore it, as Stefan suggested, or add the cert to your local trust store.

You won't have to create a certificate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the certificate e.g. with your internet browser. Click through the security information and export the certificate.

Then you need to import it into your local java keystore so that the JVM can find it. For import use the keytool which you find in your jre/bin directory. Documentation for the keytool: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/keytool.html

The default keystore is `jre/lib/security/cacerts`.

Then you can import the downloaded certificate:
`jre/bin/keytool -import -keystore jre/lib/security/cacerts -alias mycertificate -file downloads/mycertificate.cer`

Hope this helps.

P.S. If it is self signed or verified its not important at this point. Just you (your client) must trust it.